# How to improve linq query and remove in clause

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have a linq query

```
var query = from record in session.Query<Record>()
                           from brwSet in session.Query<BorrowerSet>()
                           from brw in session.Query<Borrower>()
                           where 
                           brw.PrintOrder == 1 && brwSet.PrintOrder == 0
                           && record.Package.BorrowerSet.Contains( brwSet ) 
                           && brwSet.Borrower.Contains( brw )
                           select new Summary()
                           {
                               BorrowerFirstName = brw.Contact.FirstName,
                               BorrowerLastName = brw.Contact.LastName,
                               LoanPackageID = record.Id
                           };
```

how could I rewrite this to eliminate the extra from clauses

```
from brwSet in session.Query<BorrowerSet>()
from brw in session.Query<Borrower>()
```

how can I rewrite this so I don't need the contains function on these collections?

```
record.Package.BorrowerSet.Contains( brwSet ) && brwSet.Borrower.Contains( brw )
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these proposed changes? e.g. You can replace the 2 of the froms with joins and put the join criteria in the join statement rather than the where clause, but it would do the same thing as the existing code so why bother.

Comment: I would like to get ride of the extra from clause for aesthetics.  I am more concerned with removing the contains call since this translates to an in clause in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This query doesn't have Contains.

```
var query = 
  from record in session.Query<Record>()
  from brwSet in record.Package.BorrowerSet
  where brwSet.PrintOrder == 0
  from brw is brwSet.Borrowers
  where brw.PrintOrder == 1
  select new Summary()
  {
    BorrowerFirstName = brw.Contact.FirstName,
    BorrowerLastName = brw.Contact.LastName,
    LoanPackageID = record.Id
  };
```

Comment: This does not quite work since brwSet.Borrower is a collection of borrowers.

Comment: nhibernate 3 also does not seem to support the "from brwSet in record.Package.BorrowerSet" statement